# XChat does not connect to all channels on startup

Tags: irc, xchat, freenode

I have XChat portable setup to auto connect to around 15 channels on freenode.

But on startup it only connects to 7 channels by itself. How can I fix this?

It is possible to join more channels manually.

I have searched the net for a "freenode limit" on parallel channels, but found nothing. And if I manually connect them, I can be in 20 frenode rooms and idle or chat without any problem.

I also searched for an xchat limitation in the docs, but could not find anything.

I do not want to try out different settings because this would mean leaving and joinung the same rooms over and over which would violate freenode rules and annoy the other users.

When I look at the chat config file c:\portable-apps\xchat\Data\settings\servlist_.conf it looks like this (the room names are examples but apart from that it looks the same here, and I removed the password from the B= part):

```
v=2.8.6-1
N=FreeNode
J=##super-user,#california,#internet,#anotherroom,#more,#linux,#windows,
#room7,#xyz,#chitchat,#Game.xs,#apple,#honey,#bee,#test123
B=.........
E=IRC (Latin/Unicode Hybrid)
F=27
D=0
S=irc.freenode.net
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour on my XChat. I'm using version 2.8.6-2 however.

Comment: Thank you for trying out! I found out how to fix it, see my answer below.

Comment: Oh okay, that's a bit weird IMO! All the same, glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it turns out after manually removing the line break in the channel list from the config file, all channels are connected again.

I am sure I never edited or even viewed the config file

So there was a line break in the channel list. Maybe I inserted it somehow in the config dialog.

This would be a improvement for XChat, to not accept line breaks in the config dialog where they do not make sense.

I remember I cut out the channel list from the config dialog window, edited the channels in an editor and pasted it back. Maybe the editor inserted a line break and I did not notice it.

Comment: I am not totally sure about how the newline did enter into the config file, this is only my guess. I will keep the question open for some time and if someone has a better solution I will accept that.